# I get this error when trying to use Undetected chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I can use selenium, but I encounter this error when I want to use undetected chrome driver.

```
uc.install()
chrome_driver_yolu = "C:\\Users\\omer\\Desktop\\ducky\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_yolu)
driver.get('https://distilnetworks.com')
```

and this is error

```
 WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the `executable_path` to `uc.Chrome()`. Just make sure you're using the latest version, and it will get the driver automatically for you. Eg.

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
driver.save_screenshot("nowsecure.png")
driver.quit()
```

(For https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

---

Or if you're using https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase instead (includes a modified version of `undetected-chromedriver`), make sure to pass in `uc=True`.

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
driver.save_screenshot("nowsecure.png")
driver.quit()
```